# Variable value assignment using RETURNING clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-returning

I try to do this, but it's a syntax error, what am I doing wrong?

```
declare myid := insert into oameni values(default,'lol') returning id;
```

my table:

```
create table oameni
(
 id   serial primary key,
 name varchar(10)
);
```

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You need to use the INTO clause in the RETURNING to set the value being returned into your variable:

```
DECLARE myid OAMENI.id%TYPE;

INSERT INTO oameni 
VALUES 
  (default,'lol') 
RETURNING id INTO myid;
```

You also need to specify the data type of your variable; I'm glad to see [postgresql supports %TYPE and %ROWTYPE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html).

Comment: i still get a syntax error, is this available only inside a plpgsql function, or is available in normal posgresql also ?

Comment: @Omu: How are you attempting to run this?  And what version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: I have the latest version 9 RC1, and I just pasted your code inside the sql editor

Comment: You are confusing procedural code w/ SQL. Declaring variables, cursors, loops etc are all procedural and have to be in a function or in 9.0 a DO anonymous block.

Comment: @Scott Bailey: that's the only use I could see for this, to be using within a function/stored procedure.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Sorry, I was talking to Omu who was trying to run individual plpgsql statements in a query window.

Answer (score 15):

Adding to the main answer, it's worth noting that if you are doing this outside a stored procedure, you must wrap the code in a "DO" block, like so:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
    myid mytable.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mytable (...) 
      VALUES (...)
      RETURNING id INTO myid;
END $$
```