# Returning a single value PSQL - query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql, function

I'm writing a function which takes in a ticker symbol (e.g. MSFT)

- queries a table to see if the ticker already exists, if it does return the corresponding ID
- if the ticker does not exist, insert a new record into a table and return the corresponding ID

My function is very simple:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createTicker (ticker varchar(10)) RETURNS int 
AS $$
    DECLARE
        currentTickerID int := getTickerID(ticker);
        
    BEGIN
        IF currentTickerID IS NOT NULL THEN
            RETURN currentTickerID;
        END IF;
        
        INSERT INTO ticker (name)
        VALUES             ($1)
        RETURNING ID;
    
    END;    
$$ 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Calling this function, I'm getting the following error:

'query has no destination for result data' (which is referencing the line `RETURN currentTickerID`).

I've checked other sources and can't figure out why this is causing an error. Why can't I just return from my function here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable value assignment using RETURNING clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687906/variable-value-assignment-using-returning-clause)

Comment: Yes, though doesn't explain it. I'll add the full solution to this post.

Answer (score -1):

PostgreSQL appears to treat a single row in a 1 column table as a different type to a scalar variable (different from TSQL). The final few lines of my query above needed to change from:

```
INSERT INTO ticker (name)
        VALUES             ($1)
        RETURNING ID;
```

to

```
INSERT INTO ticker (name)
VALUES             ($1)
RETURNING ID INTO currentTickerID;

RETURN currentTickerID;
```